# EF 4.1 not respecting the SQL Server columns

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, c#-4.0, model

I have just updated my MVC3 project (with C#) from `ObjectContext` to `DbContext`, but I'm getting some weird error...

I'm using the database-first approach, and I have an table with a `Name` column of type `nvarchar`, that was not null. I changed it to accept `null` in SQL Server, then I updated my `edmx` model, deleted the `.tt` files and  generated it again (with ADO.NET `DbContext`).

When I create a new object from that table, setting value to `Name` property to null I get an `DbEntityValidationException` with `The Name field is required` message in `db.SaveChanges()`.

But the table is accepting NULL on Name column! I already inserted many rows with SQL in SQL Server with NULL in `Name` column!

Anyone knows how can I solve that?

Some information

Here is my table SQL:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Pre_Register](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NULL,
    [Email] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [Permission] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Password] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

This is the automatic generated model class:

```
public partial class Pre_Register
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public byte Permission { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

And here is how I get the error:

```
Pre_Register preReg = new Pre_Register();

db.Pre_Register.Add(preReg);

preReg.Email = "dudu@mail.com";
preReg.Permission = 1;
preReg.Password = "123456";
preReg.Name = null;

// here it comes
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing i see :

Open your edmx.

Go to your Pre_Register entity, select your Name property, right click, properties, and check if Nullable field is set to true.

If it's not, set it to true. This would be strange, but I can't find another reason.

[image]

This would mean that DataBase first is... not perfect, or that something happened on your side...

Comment: Perfect!
Thankyou.. it's so sad that EF 4.1 didn't changed it automatically

Comment: @IsraelPereiraValverde fine, and I agree with you : the next question is : why does DatabaseFirst not detect nullable strings ? Or maybe you did change it manually one day ?

Comment: I don't remeber changing the Model in that way, I just renamed some relations of 1 to N... Maybe it really doen't get changed when you modify the SQLServer table =/